# Can't get jQuery scrollTop to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im trying to make a jQuery script that makes a nav bar appear after scrolling down the page 800px.

This is the file:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 800) {
    $('#fixedBar').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('#fixedBar').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#fixedBar {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}
```

Im not too sure why this jQuery isn't doing anything. All help is appreciated.

Here is the HTML in use:

```
<div id="fixedBar">
        <h1>Company</h1>
        <a href="#" class="entypo-menu showMenu"></a>
    </div>
```

Heres the head

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <!-- Links to JS/CSS/Fonts -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.maximage.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="CSS" charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/navView.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="../img/favicon.ico"/>
    <title>George | New Website</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/navBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.maximage.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/modernizr.custom.25376.js"></script>
</head>
```

Just checked the js folder and it contains the file navBar.js which has the jQuery code.

Comment: could you please make a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Your code works fine! look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5L1ukvzx/). Note that 800px is a lot of scrolling.

Comment: Are you including jQuery in your HTML file?

Comment: **You're going to have to show us enough code to reproduce the issue**.  In other words, where is your HTML markup?

Comment: Changed the scroll to just 10px instead and still not working... The file is linked correctly as other stuff works.

Comment: Did you check the console in dev tools? Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: No errors whatsoever :/

Comment: Try pasting your JS in the dev tools console. If that works, you probably are not linking navBar.js correctly.

Comment: Added <head> in edit

Comment: Just pasted in Dev console and doesn't work, the console returns: [
#document
]

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/8kzdx9wz/

```
<div id="fixedBar">nav bar</div>
```

Is your HTML written correctly and do you have enough content to scroll down to 800px on the page?

Comment: That's odd. Yes, my HTML is:  <div id="fixedBar">
  <h1>Company</h1>
  <a href="#" class="entypo-menu showMenu"></a>
 </div> and I have well over 800px.

Comment: Also, as someone stated above, make sure you're including jQuery. You can do it easily between your `<head>` tags by adding this line:

     `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Edited my <head> into question